# Identify nodes of Persistent Volume Claims

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, persistent-volume-claims

All,

Is there a way to find the nodes associated with Persistent Volume Claim.

**> kubectl get pvc -n namespace**

gives me the list of Persistent Volume Claims. But I need the node also to which each of the Claim is associated with.

Even describing the PVC does not give me the node

> **kubectl describe pvc pvcname -n namespace**

Thanks,
grajee

Comment: have you checked `pv` details?

Comment: I did run kubectl describe  on both PV & PVC but they do not contain Node name.

Comment: if you describe pod, you should see both node info and pvc info.

Comment: nodes are not necessarily associated with PV/PVC

Answer (score 4):

- whenever PVC is used by a POD , kubernetes creates a object called [volumeattachment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/config-and-storage-resources/volume-attachment-v1/) which contains the node information where the pvc is attached.

```
   - kubectl get volumeattachments | grep <pv name> // to get the volumeattachment name
   - kubectl describe volumeattachment <volumeattachment name from above command> | grep -i 'node name'
```

Comment: is it possible to get binding pod names?

Comment: i could not find any direct way of finding it , but workaround is ```kubectl get pvc --all-namespaces -o json | jq -j '.items[] | "\(.metadata.namespace), \(.metadata.name), \(.spec.volumeName)\n"' | grep <pvc name> ```

Comment: This appears not to work anymore / or maybe doesn't work in some cases. At least for me, this always comes back empty, also, considering you fix the typo: `volumeattachments`.

Comment: Do you get any output for `kubectl get volumeattachments`